# migrating Ubuntu DHCPD to OS X Server

Tags: macos, osx-server, network

My LAN includes an Ubuntu 9.04 server which runs an ISC DHCP v3 daemon. I'd like to migrate the data from that daemon to a Lion OS X Server. Is there an easy way to do this (by copying the Ubuntu `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf` and importing it into OS X Server)? Lion's `/etc/bootpd.plist` doesn't seem to contain the information about individual machines (MAC, IP): where are these stored?

Steve